# Why can we call socket.write immediately after net.createConnection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning nodejs "net" module.

Why can we call `socket.write("hello")` immediately after `socket = net.createConnection(PORT, () => {console.log("connected")}`. Why needn't we wait until the connection is established, that is, why needn't we put `socket.write` into the callback function of net.createConnection? Can we write data to a socket when it's not connected?

Answer (score 1):

> why needn't we put socket.write into the callback function of
> net.createConnection?

You could but just because `socket.write` doesn't throw any errors doesn't mean it's writing the data right then. If you look at the documentation for [`socket.write`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback) you'll see:

> The optional callback parameter will be executed when the data is
> finally written out, **which may not be immediately**.

It's still a good practice to use that parameter or use the `connect` event depending on what other logic you'd want to use.